# Kotlin common module gradle scripts with no actual platform specific code

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, cross-platform

I am trying to create a kotlin-common library, which contains shared business logic that will be used by multiple platforms. The library *itself* has *no* dependencies on anything the platforms provide. It's pure kotlin (mostly data classes and transformation helpers).

I'm using Kotlin 1.2.51 and Intellij IDEA 2018.2. I have installed the extra intellij plugin for kotlinx.

The common library also depends on https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization, but has no other dependencies.

I have spent several hours trying to wrap my head around and fix my gradle scripts, but to no avail. I want to be able to write unit tests in the `common` module. The platform specific modules shouldn't need any additional tests, as there is no platform specific logic.

The common module has all the code completion, and the build script works fine. I can write tests. When I try to run one of those tests in the IDE, it runs it through jvm (makes sense)

That jvm test fails to compile with:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx/serialization/json/JsonTreeParser`

JsonTreeParser is part of the kotlinx-serialization module. The IDE shows it fine. The common module imports it fine.

Here are my gradle scripts:

**common module**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    ext.serialization_version = '0.6.0'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin:$serialization_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'kotlin-platform-common' version '1.2.51'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common"

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"
}
```

**jvm module**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    ext.serialization_version = '0.6.0'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin:$serialization_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'kotlin-platform-jvm' version '1.2.51'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    expectedBy project(":jpatch-kotlin-common")
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
```

And my **test** in the common module

```
@Test
fun it_does_stuff() {
    assertEquals(true, true)
    val patch = JsonPatch()
    assertEquals(3, patch.cool())

    val input = """{"a": "foo", "b": 10, "c": true, "d": null}"""
    val elem: JsonElement = JsonTreeParser(input).read() // or .readFully() to throw exception if input was not consumed fully

    elem as JsonObject
    elem.keys == setOf("a", "b", "c", "d") // true
    assertEquals(JsonLiteral("foo"), elem["a"])
}
```

Straight from the documentation.

What stupid little thing am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try upgrading to Kotlin 1.2.60. There are some changes for Kotlin multi platform projects which might solve the problem

Comment: For some reason, your tests classpath misses this class, although you have it in compile classpath. I was unable to reproduce your issue on this sample project: https://github.com/sandwwraith/KotlinSerializationPlayground. You can try to compare your setup and mine.

Comment: Thank you @sandwwraith, using that example, I was able to workout my issue.

Comment: You should write the solution as an answer and mark the question as accepted.